# Associate a model with a list of other models

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models in my django app: Schedule and Topic. I want to associate a Schedule with a sequence of Topics. This seems like a simple problem, but I'm blanking on it. What is the best way to do this?

I was going to use a ForeignKey in the Topic to refer to a Schedule, so it would correctly be a many-to-one relationship of Topics to a Schedule. But I also need to keep them correctly ordered, and I'm not sure how to do this. If the db wasn't involved, I would use a linked list, but I don't think that's the ideal solution here. Do I simply give each topic a field to track it's index within the list? I would be a little worried about loosing consistency, but I can probably update all of them at once.

Comment: Use the [`order_with_respect_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/options/#order-with-respect-to) option.

Comment: Thanks. Now how can I append or insert a new Topic into this list?

Comment: @knbk: Looks like `schedule.topic_set.add` will add a topic to the schedule, is it safe to assume this will always append it? Is there an easy way to insert a topic?